# python pandas - subsetting a dataframe with integer as column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to subset a dataframe with integer as column name?

I have this pandas dataframe:

```
df
-3  -2  -1  0  col1
--------------------
a    b   c  d  text1
e    f   g  h  text2
```

I **can** do this just fine:

```
print(df.col1)
```

But I **cannot** do this to subset:

```
print(df.0)
```

Even after I convert the column name to string from integer, I still cannot do this:

```
print(df.'0')
```

in R, to subset integer-based column name, we can do this

```
df$`0`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need `[]` only for select:

```
print(df[0])
```

You can check [attribute access](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access):

> You can use this access only if the index element is a valid python identifier, e.g. **s.1** is not allowed. See [here](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) for an explanation of valid identifiers.
>
> The attribute will not be available if it conflicts with an existing method name, e.g. **s.min** is not allowed.
>
> Similarly, the attribute will not be available if it conflicts with any of the following list: **index**, **major_axis**, **minor_axis**, **items**, **labels**.
>
> In any of these cases, standard indexing will still work, e.g. **s['1']**, **s['min']**, and **s['index']** will access the corresponding element or column.
>
> The Series/Panel accesses are available starting in 0.13.0.

Comment: No problem, for this I always use `[]` for select column name. Then never this problem.

Comment: glad you can share. Thanks to him too I guess :). *PS: For some reason stackoverflow doesnt let me to accept your answer immediately.I need to wait for few minutes.*

Comment: Need always 15 minutes after posting, so after 8 minutes it is possible ;)